# Selecting multiple elements semantic-ui dropdown

Tags: semantic-ui

Select one or multiple programatically, I can do this for a select field but if I use then `<div class="ui fluid multiple search selection dropdown">` then I can't set them, this is important since I want to format the items.

According to documentation you can set (`selected([value1, value2])`    Adds a group of values as selected)

http://semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown.html#multiple-search-selection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your template is

```
<div class="ui fluid search selection dropdown multiple countries">
    <input type="hidden" name="country">
    <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
    <div class="default text">Select Country</div>
    <div class="menu">
      <div class="item" each={ c, co in countries } data-value={c.abbr}>
        <i class={c.abbr + ' flag'}></i>
        {c.name}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

And you've got many items you must set the data-value passing an array, suppose we have the array

```
countries = [{name: 'Afganistan', abbr: 'af'},
    {name: 'Bolivia', abbr: 'bo'}, 
    {name: 'Brazil', abbr: 'br'},
    {name: 'Canada', abbr: 'ca'},
    {name: 'Colombia', abbr: 'co'},
    {name: 'Ecuador', abbr: 'ec'},
    {name: 'Peru', abbr: 'pe'},
    {name: 'USA', abbr: 'us'}
    ]

// to select

$('.ui.fluid.multiple').dropdown('set selected', ['bo', 'ec'])
```